# What are the common Ethiopia Sidamo roast suggestions?

Tags: roasting, home-roasting

I usually roast Brazil and Colombia beans, and I must say I have already found the profile I've been wanting in those beans, like the chocolaty nutty, the right balance of acidity and all.

It happens that a friend gave me a couple of kilos of Ethiopia beans and I was a bit hesitant to roast it for I'm not sure what exactly is the preferred roasting style, and I might just waste a great coffee origin, yet I am excited to roast it, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends where you want to use your coffee.

If you are using you coffee in an espresso machine, you may want to prefer a darker roast, maybe Vienna Roast. Just a bit darker than medium. This will keep acidity at lower values.

If you are using French press, your cup will not be as acidic as in espresso. So, to taste the fruity flavors, it is better to roast lighter, somewhere around Light Roast to City Roast may be preferable.

Final words: it is up to your taste.

A guideline for roast naming is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_roasting).

Comment: I'll be using it for espresso actually, Thanks for that.  