# Source for Coffee beans characteristics per origin?

Tags: espresso, bean-varieties

Can I find an information/source for the characteristics for each coffee beans per origins ?

for example the acidity level, flavors, aroma , etc for 
Brazilia-Santos, Harrar, Djimmah , etc.. ?

And the names of the coffee beans per each country ? 
For example Ethiopia : 
Harrar 
Sidamo
Djimmah 
Yirgacheffee

etc ?

Comment: Hi Zahaby, welcome to Coffee SE. May I offer to check the tags before asking a new question? There is a relevant discussion [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/understanding-coffee-bean-names-as-they-relate-to-roast). After checking this, you may want to refine your question.

Comment: There is this book which is called "The world atlas of coffee" and it has exactly the information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much @MTSan I will take care later in my new posts.

Comment: @avocado1 Thanks very much I ordered it

Answer (score 1):

I roast at home the coffee I brew and I find really helpful descriptions of the cultivars from the vendor I purchase my green bean from, Sweet Maria's. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for and I'm reluctant to post a link to a commercial site, but I think they're easily found if you'd like to see if they have the kind of information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Arabica coffee beans grown in Brazil, the world's largest coffee producer and exporter, there are many varietals. Presently, the most popular seem to be: Acaia, Catucai, Rubi and Arara. Don't forget that most farms have a few of these varietals and therefore their beans represent a blend of the former.